# Where is the file that contains pinned items in Windows 10 clipboard?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard

I copied and pinned someting that messed up my clipboard, now when I open it, the cursor when I hover over it keeps spinning, and the panel is transparent.

When I turn off clipboard history, the panel is working fine (*Can't show history*)

Comment: What information gets copied to the clipboard is up to the application that writes to the clipboard.  It is possible for an application to write corrupt information to the clipboard.  This is probably more tied to the application that hosed your clipboard than the Windows bug on being able to show or interpret corrupt data.  Not cool that windows barfs but probably not it's fault.

Comment: I can't remember well, but I copied some "vmess://" and the problem occurred. I also have the Python script that will decode the base64 string after the "vmess://" and change the **port** from *54000* to *80*, encode it, and copy it to the clipboard using [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/). The clipboard history is working fine now, so just ignore it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files of pinned items reside in folder(s) in:
`C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Clipboard\Pinned`

You can problemlessly clear anything that's inside there if you wish and e.g. the regular wipe in the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> menu doesn't work for you for some reason. You might want to wipe all the contents of `Clipboard` dir if just deleting `Pinned` contents doesn't help.

I would much more recommend using [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/) as the clipboard manager though. It's way easier to manage and has more useful functionalities.

Comment: After deleted these files, it worked flawlessly. I will try the [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/) too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *clearing* clipboard history? In [GroovyPost](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/clear-your-clipboard-history-on-windows-10/) :

1. "In the Settings menu, press System > Clipboard. In the Clipboard menu, press the Clear option in the Clear clipboard data section at the bottom."
2. "[W]ipe your data by disabling the new clipboard history feature entirely—press the Clipboard history slider (toggle for *off/on*) to do this."
3. [Unpin all Clipboard History](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/109868-pin-unpin-items-clipboard-history-windows-10-a.html) items and reboot.

BTW, there are some limitation in Windows clipboard history, as well as faults, so you might consider a free third-party alternative such as [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/copyq/).

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. Delete these pinned items is the only option.